# Least squares from bayesian perspective

Tags: probability, least-squares

I am studying least squares estimation. However, I cannot understand the following formula.
I do not know how to find distribution of y and x and beta. I am not even sure that they are random variable and probability of data does not make sense at all and why noise term is the back bone of the probability equation. Can you help me figure this out?

[image]

Comment: Which formula? There are several equations written on that page. The $x_i$ are not random. Given a value of $x_i$, $y_i$ is assumed to be equal to $\beta^T x_i + \epsilon_i$ where $\epsilon_i$ is a random variable distributed as $N(0,\sigma^2)$, independent of the other $\epsilon_j$'s. The likelihood function says assuming what I said in the previous sentence is true, what is the likelihood that we observed the data $\{(x_i,y_i)\}_{i=1}^n$?

Comment: @kccu formula that gives likelyhood function. I do not understand its deriviation and also I do not know how to find distribution of X,Y and BETA if they have any and is it possible to open p(yi|xi,beta) and put values?

Comment: Again, which line of the likelihood function? The first line is just the definition of likelihood function. For the second, it's because of what I said in my comment: *given* a value of $x_i$ (and the vector $\beta$), $y_i$ is assumed to be equal to $\beta^Tx_i+\epsilon_i$. In other words, $y_i-\beta^Tx_i=\epsilon_i$ is assumed to be $N(0,\sigma)^2$. So $p(y_i|x_i,\beta)$ is given by the normal density function on the next line. All of the randomness is contained in $\epsilon_i$. That means $y_i$ is also random (but depends on the value of $x_i$ and $\beta$). $x_i$ and $\beta$ are fixed.

Comment: @kccu thank you a lot you enlightened me. I got it now. I just freak out when probabilities are involved

Comment: You're welcome. Small correction - my previous comment should say $N(0,\sigma^2)$, not $N(0,\sigma)^2$ but it's too late to edit.

Comment: @kccu can you also tell me how to center data? I could not find any info on this one.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what it's referring to in your notes, but typically "centering" refers to adding/subtracting a constant from all the data to make its mean equal to $0$. So it might be referring to subtracting $\beta^Tx_i$ from each $y_i$ (but note that $\beta^T x_i$ is not a constant - it depends on $i$).